# multi thread capable python debugger

Tags: python, debugging

Does the ipython debugger (ipdb) support multiple threads? It seems that it doesn't but I'm really surprised and am looking for **confirmation**, because the webpage for it doesn't say one way or the other.
I run linux (pop!_os) on a System76 Darter Pro, and am looking for a debugger that can debug multiple threads. I use the Spyder IDE via Anaconda.

Comment: Eclipse IDE has excellent debugging support for debugging multithreaded apps, installs PyDev from the marketplace. It’s a pain in the ass to get setup, but once working you will get the time back.